# Adding custom numbers to sidebar in only Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an external site provider as a small demo site (for a proof of concept) so I havent build it myself.

But I wanted to be able to do this in pure JS and no external libraries (one so I can learn from others and two imports get stripped).

I have an `<aside id="sidebar">` and an `<ul>` in a sidebar that generates the headings (H1-H6) from the body, similar to this:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>Black Books</a></li>            <-- H1
  <ul>
    <li><a>Season 2</a></li>             <-- H2
    <ul>
      <li><a>Episode 1</a></li>          <-- H3
      <ul>
        <li><a>Characters</a></li>       <-- H4
        <li><a>Quotes</a></li>           <-- H4
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

I was wondering how would I be able to prefix the

tags with the level that they are in from the heading tag? So the output would be this:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>1. Black Books</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a>1.1. Season 2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a>1.1.1. Episode 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>1.1.1.1. Characters</a></li>
        <li><a>1.1.1.2. Quotes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

But also be able to set a scope so the numbering can start at H2 and end at H4 (instead of a blanket H1-H6 rule):

```html
<!-- starting in a scope (only H2-H3) -->
<ul>
  <li><a>Black Books</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a>1.1. Season 2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a>1.1.1. Episode 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Characters</a></li>
        <li><a>Quotes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Im not that good with Javascript and was hoping there was some help or pointers :)

Comment: Why do this with Javascript? This is 100% [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters) territory. The MDN article _literally_ covers this exact example =)

Comment: Hi Mike @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans! How would you do thar with CSS counters or how could I start at 2. or 60. if I wanted to? From what I reading it starts at 1. or I'd have to hard code CSS for each page without being dynamic

Comment: you use the [counter-set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-set) property. Define the counter on the parent element, and set it to the value you need, and a counter increment rule on the elements that increase the count (and you do that separately for each counter that needs to "not start at 1"). Quite a few good tutorials easily googled that explain how to use counters both for simple and ridiculously complex use cases.